# Adding SSL to a local computer and running my Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, ssl, https

new here and new to programming. I hope you all can help me figure this out because I wasn't really able to find what I needed online.

I am working on a project for class and this week's assignment is to implement SSL on my local computer and run the email application I created the previous week (if needed I can provide that as well).

Those were all the instructions that were given and I am assuming that when I run my application in Eclipse, instead of it populating http://localhost:8080/project_name on the address bar I should be able to use https://localhost:8443/project_name. Indicating there is a secure connection.

I am using:
Java version - 16.0.2, Apache Tomcat - 9.0.56, and Eclipse IDE 2021-09.

Will this guide https://www.computerworld.com/article/2763228/how-to-enable-https-in-tomcat.html work?

I have created a cert using mkcert and this guide https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#windows and also used this guide https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl, both of which I got about halfway on because I wasnt sure I was doing it right.

Just need some guidance on what is the best and easiest method to approach the task. I feel like im kind of all over the place.

Thanks in advance for any help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like https, not ssl.

Comment: You're right. I did some more digging and stepped away from the computer for a while. I am trying to get my Tomcat to see my .keystore and the "tomcat" certificate that I created. I found my .keystore, and I can use the CMD prompt to locate and see my Tomcat when I use keytool -list, but all the documentation and the course book is old and hard to match up what and where to fill in those blanks.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. well the first portion. Ill work on the next portion tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.